# How to complare one Master table against several child tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one master table (`PO_BreakOutAll`) with ~3000 rows made up of only two columns (`PO_ID`, `PO_LN_NO`) which together make up the primary key. I also have several other tables each with a subset of the data from the master table (or so it is supposed to be). All the tables are the same schema as the master table.

All tables have this exact schema:

```
PO_ID     char(5) PK
PO_LN_NO  int     PK
```

I need to do two different types of comparisons for validation and to find duplicates.

First to make sure that every row in the master table exists in one, and only one, of the other child tables.

Second I need to make sure that no row is duplicated across any of the child tables. The same row can exist in two or more child tables and I need to find them.

I can do each table in a separate query but have not figured out how to write one query that compares all the child tables at once.

Here is what I have so far but it does not work:

```
SELECT a.PO_ID as all_PO,
       a.PO_LN_NO,
       c.PO_ID as Cummings_PO,
       c.PO_LN_NO,
       f.PO_ID as filter_PO,
       f.PO_LN_NO,
       fo.PO_ID as fixedObl_PO,
       fo.PO_LN_NO
FROM 
       PO_BreakOutAll   a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       PO_Cummins       c   ON (c.PO_ID = a.PO_ID AND c.PO_LN_NO = a.PO_LN_NO)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       PO_Filters       f   ON (f.PO_ID = a.PO_ID AND f.PO_LN_NO = a.PO_LN_NO)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       PO_FixedOblig    fo  ON (fo.PO_ID = a.PO_ID AND fo.PO_LN_NO = a.PO_LN_NO)
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` the child tables in a *common table expression* (CTE). Include a column that identifies the child table. Join the CTE to the master table in two ways: One to identify gaps in the expected 1:1. Two to identify master entities that have duplicates in the CTE.

Comment: @andy holaday, Thanks, I created two fiddles based on your comments. The one for finding the duplicates is giving me fits, I need to see both the row that ends up being duplicated and the duplicate so I know which one need to be deleted. If I show only those with RowNumber > 1 then I lose that functionality. Here is the fiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac36d/15 . The other fiddle to find  missing rows works great. Here it is  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd396/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @gordon linoff has an overall solution. If you want to work with the CTE paradigm here is an [example based on your Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac36d/32) that answers the duplicate question:

```
WITH CTE (PO_ID,PO_LN_NO,TableName) AS

(SELECT 
 PO_ID,
 PO_LN_NO,
 'Cummings' as TableName


 FROM PO_Cummins
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 
 PO_ID,
 PO_LN_NO,
 'Filters' as TableName

 FROM PO_Filters
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 
 PO_ID,
 PO_LN_NO,
 'Office' as TableName

 FROM PO_Office )

SELECT
  PO_BreakOutAll.PO_ID, 
  PO_BreakOutAll.PO_LN_NO,
  CHILD_DATA.TABLENAME AS DUP_TABLENAME
FROM
  PO_BreakOutAll
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT PO_ID, PO_LN_NO, COUNT(1) AS DUP_COUNTER
  FROM CTE
  GROUP BY PO_ID, PO_LN_NO
  HAVING COUNT(1) > 1 
  ) DUPS ON DUPS.PO_ID = PO_BreakOutAll.PO_ID AND DUPS.PO_LN_NO = PO_BreakOutAll.PO_LN_NO
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT PO_ID, PO_LN_NO, TABLENAME
  FROM CTE
  ) CHILD_DATA
  ON CHILD_DATA.PO_ID = PO_BreakOutAll.PO_ID AND CHILD_DATA.PO_LN_NO = PO_BreakOutAll.PO_LN_NO
ORDER BY PO_ID, PO_LN_NO, DUP_TABLENAME
```

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, exactly what I needed. Just a tiny bit over my head to create it on my own.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `join` for this; I would use `union all`.  Here is a way to get a count of how the records overlap among the tables:

```
select isAll, isCummins, isFilters, isOblig, count(*)
from (select PO_ID, PO_LN_NO, sum(isAll) as isAll, sum(isCummins) as isCummins,
             sum(isFilters) as isFilters, sum(isOblig) as isOblig
      from ((select PO_ID, PO_LN_NO, 1 as isAll, 0 as isCummins, 0 as isFilters, 1 as isOblig
             from PO_BreakOutAll
            ) union all
            (select PO_ID, PO_LN_NO, 0, 1, 0, 0
             from PO_Cummins
            ) union all
            (select PO_ID, PO_LN_NO, 0, 0, 1, 0
             from PO_Filters
            ) union all
            (select PO_ID, PO_LN_NO, 0, 0, 0, 1
             from PO_FixedOblig
            )
           ) t
      group by PO_ID, PO_LN_NO
     ) t
group by isAll, isCummins, isFilters, isOblig;
```

If you want to find rows that fail your test, just use the subquery with `where` conditions:

```
      select PO_ID, PO_LN_NO, sum(isAll) as isAll, sum(isCummins) as isCummins,
             sum(isFilters) as isFilters, sum(isOblig) as isOblig
      from ((select PO_ID, PO_LN_NO, 1 as isAll, 0 as isCummins, 0 as isFilters, 1 as isOblig
             from PO_BreakOutAll
            ) union all
            (select PO_ID, PO_LN_NO, 0, 1, 0, 0
             from PO_Cummins
            ) union all
            (select PO_ID, PO_LN_NO, 0, 0, 1, 0
             from PO_Filters
            ) union all
            (select PO_ID, PO_LN_NO, 0, 0, 0, 1
             from PO_FixedOblig
            )
           ) t
      group by PO_ID, PO_LN_NO
      having sum(isAll) <> 1 or
             (sum(isAll) = 1 and (sum(isCummins) + sum(isFilters) + sum(isOblig) <> 1)
             );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it doesn't seem to work. I get an error even after fixing the minor mistake of selecting c.Po_LN_NO when the table was not aliased. I get this: All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists. Will try and figure this out on my own but it is a bit over my head right now.

Comment: @AlanFisher . . . It should work now.  I had started the query thinking I need to identify the source of each row.  So, the first was `'All' as which` and so on.  Then I realized that flags are a better approach for this problem -- and I didn't clean up that column on the rest of the subqueries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I created two SQL fiddles. This one http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac36d/15  sort of works but I need it to work better. Any row with a RowNumber greater than 1 is a duplicate. That's fine but I need to only see the row and the row being duplicated. The fiddle shows every row includeing those not duplicated. If I were to only show rows with Rownumber > 1 I would lose the original row that ended up being duplicated and wouldn't know which table it was duplicated from. The other fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd396/1 shows orphaned rows and works perfectly.

Comment: Did you try the queries in the answer?  They may do what you want.